# UILabel with 2 lines, how to truncate each line independently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm trying to display a `UILabel` with 2 lines with something like this:

```
"Here is the first line (a long one) and that's it"
"And this is the second line with random number of chars"
```

With Truncate Tail it displays this:

```
"Here is the first line (a long one) and that's ..."
```

My goal is to display:

```
"Here is the first line (a long .."
"And this is the second line wit.."
```

Is there a way to do this with `UILabel` set to 2 lines and without using 2 `UILabel's` ?

Comment: Do you have line breaks as part of the text ? if so, you could calculate the text length for given control settings and truncate the lines individually. Otherwise I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Excatly, I did that and it works. But when the screen is rotated to landscape, I'd like that each line "expands" and that's why I'm asking this. Any thought ?

Comment: Good point, you need to redo calculations each time the drawing area   or the text is changed. It can be done by subclassing `UILabel` and overriding `setText:` and `layoutSubviews`, although the former may not cover all the text setters and the latter might be not the best method to change the text at, beware of creating an infinite recursion.

Comment: can we implement like this ? [yourLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

Comment: I think @A-Live is right. If you `setNumberOfLines:0`, then it may expand the height of the `UILabel`. Maybe 2 `UILabel's` is the only way to do this in an "elegant" way.

Comment: @Patrick L. the idea to create your own control that would have two (or any number really) internal `UILabel`s sounds good for me.

Answer (score -3):

Split the string on `\n` to create two strings. Then create 2 UILabels set to `numberOfLines = 1` and `lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail`. Lay them out in the view, one on top of the other.

Comment: Question specifically states one label not two.

Answer (score -4):

First, you need to set the numbers of lines to 0(infinite number of lines);

```
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Next, you can break wherever you want by doing this:

```
textLabel.text = "str1 \n str2"
```

Comment: The issue isn’t the line breaks, it’s the truncation. This won’t help that.